# akka system.scheduler().scheduleAtFixedRate can i change value of Duration.ofMinutes at run time?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

below code is in INIT method of main class

```
system.scheduler()
.scheduleAtFixedRate(Duration.ZERO,
Duration.ofMinutes(settings.getInterval()),
readActor,TriggerBatch.fromTimer(),
system.dispatcher(),
ActorRef.noSender());
```

once the buisness logic is excuted which is receiveBuilder() method then
i need to change Duration.ofMinutes value at run time

i tried below solutions

```
  solution 1. 
  Config config = new CachingConfig(ConfigFactory.load());
  Config config1 = config.withValue("service- 
  name.scheduler.interval",ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("20"));// in application.conf value for interval is =1 
  config1.getInt("service-name.scheduler.interval"); 

solution 2. 
Config overrides = ConfigFactory.parseString("service-name.scheduler.interval=20");
Config actualConfig = overrides.withFallback(ConfigFactory.load());
actualConfig.getInt("service-name.scheduler.interval");
```

this solutions works but scheduler is not taking updated value its still taking old one which is service-name.scheduler.interval = 1

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options, assuming that you control the init method where  `system.scheduler().scheduleAtFixedRate` is being called.

First, calling `scheduleAtFixedRate` gives you a `Cancellable` back.  You can thus `cancel` the `Cancellable` and set a new interval for the scheduling.  You would need to pass that `Cancellable` to the actor so that it's accessible in the `receiveBuilder` method (you can either pass it via the `Props` when creating an actor, or through a message sent to the actor).

As an alternative, you could have init spawn an actor for the purpose of managing the scheduled sends of the messages.  That actor's state would be the `Cancellable` from `scheduleAtFixedRate`, and you could send it messages to change the interval between sends.